# javascript window redirect pass parameters securely (post)

Tags: javascript, parameters, dns, navigation, passwords

I have a scenario where page navigation is done from one domain to another.
For example, navigation is done from
http://www.foo.com to 
http://www.bar.com on button click in javascript

While redirecting, I need to send username and password securely from the first domain to the second domain.

How do I send these parameters?

I do not want to use GET and send it across the URL as it is not secure to send password in that manner.
Broswer's localStorage and SessionStorage did not work as the domains are different.

Window.open does opens the second domain in the same page ('_self') but the parameters are lost. On top of that window.open has the drawback of popup blockers blocking it

Cookie did not work.

I want to redirect from Site A to Site B and pass the username and password the user entered on Site A to Site B

Comment: "I do not want to use GET and send it across the URL as it is not secure" — What sort of security problem does that have which concerns you? It is hard to give you an answer because you haven't said what actions the security should prevent and who it should prevent from performing them.

Comment: "Cookie worked" — That's hard to believe, cookies can't pass data between second level domains.

Comment: My bad. I just checked. Cookie did no work as its not visible in the other domain. By security with GET, I meant, I do not want to ass data across url as htt://www.bar.com?password='some_password'. This is not secure as the password is visible across the URL. The second domain can have a listener to red parameters, but I am not sure how to send data

Comment: "This is not secure as the password is visible across the URL" — Why is that a problem? Who are you worried is going to see it?

Comment: Eavesdroppers. How is sending username and password across URL safe? Anybody can see use them and hack the accounts

Comment: By "anyone" I take it you mean "Anyone standing behind your visitor and staring intently at their monitor"? Otherwise, it doesn't matter if the data is in the URL or not, if it isn't encrypted then it is visible over the network. (OK, not quite true, unless you configure your server right the passwords will also get stored in the access log).

Comment: I cant send the data over the URL, even if its encrypted. Its a very high security domain. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways:

1) Use a POST: Create a `<form/>` in your webpage and place some hidden variables on the fly using javascript and then post it to another website.

2) Use Headers: Can you see if you can set header?

3) Use Token: You can try using Token, which you can use instead of user+pwd combination. So what happens is you redirect from website A to B using a token embedded in the URL and website B validates the token to an API available on website A before it authenticates the user. You can make these token self-expiring after X seconds.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. I see the 3rd option of tokenizing as a way of OAuth 2.0 protocol where the username and password is hidden. What I want here is to send the username and password from Site A to Site B securely and Site B should know the username and password.

Comment: if all you want is to send user/pwd then option 3 is absolute. it's just an alternate way to authenticate w/o sending actual credentials.

Comment: I want to send the username and password. They need to be passed to the second domain from the first

Comment: Seems like the first comment on using <form> is turning out reasonable. I used something like var form = $('<form action="http://bar:8080/signin.html" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="parameter1" value="sample" /></form>');
$('body').append(form);
$(form).submit();. Can you please suggest how to read this parameter on the signin.html page on load?

Comment: Isn't using token a security risk? What if some other user copies the same token? He will get all the permissions and can hit restricted API's. How to secure this using 3rd option?

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear what your security implications are here:

> While redirecting, I need to send username and password securely from the first domain to the second domain.
>
> I do not want to use GET and send it across the URL as it is not secure to send password in that manner.

Is it site B should not know the password or is it you are concerned about someone listening on the request and replaying it?

At any rate, the only secure way is

- Site A hands you a token (could be a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/))
- you send this token with the request to site B.
- Site B takes this token and asks site A to validate it.
- After positive validation, Site B creates a session for you.

Everything else (using POST instead of GET) is insecure as well, it is trivial to listen in to a POST request.

Comment: Site B should know the username and password. I do not want eavesdropping to happen. I want to navigate from site A to site B and send password from A to B securely.

Comment: Then send the request via https.

Comment: Its not a server side call. Just normal page navigation from one domain to another with parameter passing. No server is involved. Only client navigation.

Comment: Still, if you want to avoid eavesdropping, server B should serve the content via https and the client should POST to `https://server-b.com/something.php`.

Comment: B is not a server. It is a client. It is a web page. I am passing username and password from one web page (A) to another (B). Both are web pages.

Comment: I don't get it. `Site B` must be served from somewhere? If you redirect from web page A on domain A to web page B on domain B, you are requesting a page from a different server.

Comment: Yes. B has a server on its own which is different from A. What I want is send data from A and just do an alert on B to check if it has received it. How do I do that?